# iOS 9 JSON Parsing loop

Tags: ios, json, database, swift2, ios9

I'm creating an app that should retrieve some JSON from a database.

This is how my JSON looks:

```
[{"id":"1","longitude":"10","latitude":"10","visibility":"5","timestampAdded":"2015-10-01 15:01:39"},{"id":"2","longitude":"15","latitude":"15","visibility":"5","timestampAdded":"2015-10-01 15:06:25"}]
```

And this is the code i use:

```
if let jsonResult = JSON as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {

                    let longitudeValue = jsonResult[0]["longitude"]
                    let latitudeValue = jsonResult[0]["latitude"]
                    let visibilityValue = jsonResult[0]["visibility"]

                    print(longitudeValue!)
                    print(latitudeValue!)
                    print(visibilityValue!)
}
```

As you can see it only gets the first chunk from the JSON and if there are no JSON at all it will crash, but if i want it to count the amount and make an array out of it like this:

```
var longitudeArray = [10, 15]
var latitudeArray = [10, 15]
```

And so on...

I also need this to be apple watch compatible so i can't use SwiftyJSON.

What do i do? I really hope you can help me!

Thanks.

---

### SOLVED!

Problems was solved by "Eric D."

This is the code:

```
do {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "YOU URL HERE"),
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {

        print(jsonResult)
        let longitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $0["longitude"] as? String }
        let latitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $0["latitude"] as? String }
        print(longitudeArray)
        print(latitudeArray)

    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.description)
}
```

Thank you soo much Eric!! :-)

Comment: You're only getting one value because you're only extracting the first value from the array `jsonResult[0]`. And it crashes if it's empty because trying to get a non-existent index from an array crashes.

Comment: Use a for loop with `jsonResult.length()`

Comment: why dont you use NSJSONSerialization? This will give you a complete dictionary for the provided data. Than you can fillter this dictionary with the names of linguted and latitude and fill the result in the array

Comment: Don't forget that I was only using `NSData(contentsOfURL: url)` for running tests in the Playground, don't use it in prod, use an asynchronous method instead to download your data. :)

Comment: Yes i know thank you Eric :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` to get an array of your elements:

```
let longitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $0["longitude"] as? String }
let latitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $0["latitude"] as? String }
```

etc.

`flatMap` is like `map` but unwraps optionals, which is adequate because we need to safely cast the type of the object we get from each dictionary in the json array.

`$0` represents the object in the current iteration of `flatMap` of the array it's applied to.

---

If you're currently using SwiftyJSON, then that would be:

```
let longitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $1["longitude"].string }
let latitudeArray = jsonResult.flatMap { $1["latitude"].string }
```

because `.string` is SwiftyJSON's optional String value getter.

But as you said, you don't want to use it (anymore), so you need to use `NSJSONSerialization` to decode your JSON data, there's plenty of examples on the Web and on SO. Then you will be able to use my original answer.

Comment: When i do that Xcode goes all white and won't compile :-/

Comment: Are you sure you're using Xcode 7? This code is for Swift 2, as your question is tagged with it, so it needs Xcode 7.

Comment: Yes i am using Xcode 7 (Xcode 7.1 Beta to be more precise)

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 7.1b. I don't know why you can't use this, this is absolutely standard code. You may have a problem with your Xcode install.

Comment: Let's make a test if you're ok: run [this test code](https://gist.github.com/ericdke/3c7cf6c3c6659e679247) in a Playground. Just replace the URL by yours. Then tell me what happened.

Comment: You're welcome. And it means you have an unknown problem with your current code base, because if my answer works in a Playground it should also work in your project. :) I hope you'll find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're already getting an array with all of the elements (not just the first one. you're simply only accessing the first one). `jsonResult` is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary (in this case, based on the json you provided) contains these elements: id, longitude, latitude, visibility and timestampAdded. In order to access each of them, you can simply loop over `jsonResult` and access the i'th element (and not always the 0 element). This will also prevent the crash you're experiencing with the json is blank or invalid (since you'll only be going over the valid elements in `jsonResult`.

This will give you the flexibility to create the custom arrays you wish to create (in order to create an array of all of the longitudes, for example, you will simply add that element to the new array while looping over `jsonResult`). However, if you'd like to save yourself the trouble of manually building these arrays and assuming you have control over the json structure, I would recommend changing the received json to the relevant structure (a dictionary or arrays instead of an array of dictionaries), so it would better fit your needs and provide you the results in the relevant format right "out of the box".

Comment: Yes i knew that. Apparently i wasn't clear enough but thanks for the answer i appreciate it! :-) But how do i count the amount of it?

Comment: get `jsonResult.length()`